# can i map 2 testcases in jira-xray to 1 testcases in automation script and upload junit xml test results

Tags: jira-xray

We are using NightwatchJS automation tool for testing. We have 2 testcases in Jira-xray and 1 testcase in automation. When we run auomation, JUnit xml test results contains only 1 testcase. If JUnit xml test results are uploaded, will it mark 2 testcsaes mapped in Jira as pass/fail?

Answer (score 0):

It should only map to one test case, following the rules described in the [integration specifics page](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Taking+advantage+of+JUnit+XML+reports).

Xray will try to find an existing "Generic" Test issue having a Generic Definition field composed by the classname and name attributes of the  element; these are used as a unique identifier for the test.